# Shouldn't UFW configured Iptables deny access before the request reaches our Unbutu 16.04 hosted Nginx server?

Tags: nginx, iptables, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, ufw

We are using ufw to configure iptables.

We have numerous rules denying access from ip addresses that use bots. Here is one example:

```
sudo ufw deny from 0.1.0.0/0.1.255.255
```

These bots are attempting to access our site via an IP address rather than our domain names.

We have configured our Nginx blocks to throw and error if an attempt is made to access content via an IP.

Shouldn't the UFW configured Iptables rule deny access before the request reaches Nginx?

Comment: It depends on your full iptables ruleset. This rule by itself doesn't tell if the packets are blocked or not.